# How to get the value of the function "PMT" - (algorithm for the function)

Tags: excel, math, finance

Can you help me to get the manual calc for get the result of the function PAGO from excel using the value of future value, for example this method

=PMT(0.0158,12,-300000,0.6*300000)  return 13,900.50 if I remove the future value the function is =PMT(0.0158,12,-300000,0) and the result is 27,641.20

in this second example the function for get this value is ((Ir * (1 + Ir)^Np ) * M ) / ((1+ Ir)^Np -1)
where Ir = interes rate, Np number of payments and M the financing amount.

but Im not sure how I can add the additional value (future value) in this function.

Answer (score 0):

The function is for calculating loan repayment installments. PV if Present amount of the loan outstanding. FV is the loan amount that will be outstanding after the NPER(number of installments) payments.

So, can there be different amounts outstanding FVs for the same loan at the same time?

If you are planning to calculate loan installments in blocks of periods. Say 12 months, 18 months and hence, there will be different FVs at different times. But in that case you should have a new cell for calculation. Where FV of previous block will become PV for calculation block.

More the PV more will be the result amount
More the FV less will be the result amount

Please see if image below helps.

[image]
[Link](https://www.caclubindia.com/share_files/emi-calculator-scheduler-4669.asp)